# Error al crear proyecto en laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5

Cordial saludo estimados
intento crear un proyecto en laravel en ubuntu y al iniciar el proyecto en el navegador sale que ha ocurrid un error y no muestra nada.
Alguien me puede ayudar por favor. Adjunto lo que muestra al seguir el proceso de creación.
gracias

> root@ubuntu:/var/www/html# composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel laravel5.5
>   Installing laravel/laravel (v5.5.0)
>     - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.5.0)
>       Loading from cache
>
> Created project in laravel5.5 Loading composer repositories with
>   package information Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>     - Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v2.4.0)
>       Loading from cache
>
> - Installing symfony/css-selector (v3.3.9)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles (2.2.0)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.5.0)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing symfony/var-dumper (v3.3.9)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing symfony/routing (v3.3.9)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing symfony/process (v3.3.9)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v3.3.9)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v3.3.9)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing psr/log (1.0.2)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing symfony/debug (v3.3.9)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v3.3.9)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing symfony/finder (v3.3.9)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing symfony/console (v3.3.9)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing doctrine/lexer (v1.0.1)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing egulias/email-validator (2.1.2)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v6.0.1)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing paragonie/random_compat (v2.0.10)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing ramsey/uuid (3.7.0)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing psr/simple-cache (1.0.0)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing psr/container (1.0.0)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing symfony/translation (v3.3.9)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing nesbot/carbon (1.22.1)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing mtdowling/cron-expression (v1.2.0)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing monolog/monolog (1.23.0)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing league/flysystem (1.0.41)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing erusev/parsedown (1.6.3)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing doctrine/inflector (v1.2.0)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing laravel/framework (v5.5.3)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing fideloper/proxy (3.3.4)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-color (0.1)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter (v0.3.2)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir (0.1)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing nikic/php-parser (v3.1.1)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing psy/psysh (v0.8.11)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing laravel/tinker (v1.0.2)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing filp/whoops (2.1.10)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing fzaninotto/faker (v1.7.1)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing hamcrest/hamcrest-php (v1.2.2)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing mockery/mockery (0.9.9)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing sebastian/version (2.0.1)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing sebastian/resource-operations (1.0.0)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing sebastian/recursion-context (3.0.0)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing sebastian/object-reflector (1.1.1)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing sebastian/object-enumerator (3.0.3)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing sebastian/global-state (2.0.0)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing sebastian/exporter (3.1.0)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing sebastian/environment (3.1.0)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing sebastian/diff (2.0.1)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing sebastian/comparator (2.0.2)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing doctrine/instantiator (1.0.5)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing phpunit/php-text-template (1.2.1)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects (4.0.4)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing phpunit/php-timer (1.0.9)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing phpunit/php-file-iterator (1.4.2)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing theseer/tokenizer (1.1.0)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup (1.0.1)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing phpunit/php-token-stream (2.0.1)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing phpunit/php-code-coverage (5.2.2)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing webmozart/assert (1.2.0)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-common (1.0.1)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing phpdocumentor/type-resolver (0.4.0)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock (4.1.1)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing phpspec/prophecy (v1.7.2)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing phar-io/version (1.0.1)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing phar-io/manifest (1.0.1)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing myclabs/deep-copy (1.6.1)
>     Loading from cache
> - Installing phpunit/phpunit (6.3.0)
>     Loading from cache
>
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
>   
>   root@ubuntu:/var/www/html# cd laravel5.5
>   
>   root@ubuntu:/var/www/html/laravel5.5# php artisan serve
>   
>   Laravel development server started: < http://127.0.0.1:8000 >
>
> En el log aparece:
>
> > [2017-09-12 20:33:34] production.ERROR: No application encryption key has been specified. {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code:
> >     0): No application encryption key has been specified. at
> >     /var/www/html/laravel5.5/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/EncryptionServiceProvider.php:42)
> >     
> >     [stacktrace]
> >     /var/www/html/laravel5.5/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php(1035): Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\Encryption\{closure}(NULL)
> >     /var/www/html/laravel5.5/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/EncryptionServiceProvider.php(46):
> >     tap(NULL, Object(Closure))
> >     /var/www/html/laravel5.5/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/EncryptionServiceProvider.php(24):
> >     Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider->key(Array)
> >     /var/www/html/laravel5.5/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(749):
> >     Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\Encryption\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application),
> >     Array)
> >     /var/www/html/laravel5.5/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(631):
> >     Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure))
> >     /var/www/html/laravel5.5/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(586):
> >     Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('encrypter', Array)
> >     /var/www/html/laravel5.5/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(721):
> >     Illuminate\Container\Container->make('encrypter', Array)
> >     /var/www/html/laravel5.5/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(885):
> >     Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('encrypter')
> >     /var/www/html/laravel5.5/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(813):
> >     Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
> >     /var/www/html/laravel5.5/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(780):
> >     Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveDependencies(Array)
> >     /var/www/html/laravel5.5/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(631):
> >     Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\\Http\\Middle...')
> >     /var/www/html/laravel5.5/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(586):
> >     Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('App\\Http\\Middle...',
> >     Array)
> >     /var/www/html/laravel5.5/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(721):
> >     Illuminate\Container\Container->make('App\\Http\\Middle...',
> >     Array)
> >     /var/www/html/laravel5.5/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(215):
> >     Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('App\\Http\\Middle...')
> >     /var/www/html/laravel5.5/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(189):
> >     Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->terminateMiddleware(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request),
> >     Object(Illuminate\Http\Response))
> >     /var/www/html/laravel5.5/public/index.php(60): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->terminate(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request),
> >     Object(Illuminate\Http\Response))
> >     /var/www/html/laravel5.5/server.php(21): require_once('/var/www/html/l...')
> >      {main} "}

Comment: ¿cuál es el error que muestra Laravel? Por favor revisa los logs y edita la pregunta para agregar la información respectiva.

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta. Ya adicione el mensaje del log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A veces no se crea el archivo .env asi que tienes que utilizar este comando `composer run-script post-root-package-install`

aunque ahora se crean los proyectos de esta manera:

```
laravel new "nombre_proyecto"
composer update
composer run-script post-root-package-install
```

cuando te aparezca el error de key utilizas el siguiente comando

```
php artisan key:generate
```

disculpa, no lei completo el mensaje de error que mostraste.
espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. voy a revisar

Comment: Agradezco tus aportes me han servido pero sigo con problemas. efectivamente el archivo .env no se crea y sigo lo que me dices pero no tengo éxito. me podrias recomendar algun recurso electrónico para revisar todo desde cero? muchas gracias